# RegExp que detecte si coincide con una palabra, considerando espacios y/o letras duplicadas

Tags: nodejs, regex

Trabajo con **NodeJS**, tenía un sistema que verificaba si un string contenía cierta palabra bloqueada, sin embargo, era fácil de esquivar el sistema. (Reemplazaba todos los carácteres unicode a `""`, así que es muy poco eficiente).

Me gustaría utilizar **RegExp** en caso de que sea posible, (usando [regex101](https://regex101.com) para simularlo), el objetivo es detectar si una palabra ha sido escrita, pero el usuario intenta evitar que el sistema lo detecte.

Supongamos que la palabra `fuck` está bloqueada, entonces cuando el usuario lo escriba (de manera explícita), el sistema debe dar positivo, sin embargo, también debe hacerlo si repite una (o varias) letra/s (ej `fuuck`), si pone un espacio (ej `f uck`) o múltiples. Pero no debería dar positivo en palabras como `brainfuck`.

Lo que el sistema hará es, `/<regex>/.test(string)`, y cuando éste devuelva `true`, la aplicación ejecutará unos métodos externos (de una librería externa).

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo hacer tal cosa? En mi actual sistema hago `.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi, "").toUpperCase()` para eliminar todos los carácteres unicode, y luego buscar si existen palabras que coincidan con alguna de las que están guardadas en un array. Usando lo siguiente: `message.split(" ").filter(w => wordFilter.includes(w))` (wordFilter son todas las palabras filtradas por el servidor).

Comment: Pero como está claro, ese sistema es muy poco eficiente (en los l33t, eliminaría los números en lugar de reemplazarlos por letras) y tampoco detecta palabras bloqueadas que tienen espacios u otras letras en su interior (repetidos, por ejemplo).

Comment: Vale, editaré la pregunta para centrarme en el primer paso.

Comment: @AntonioRoman: `...sistema que verificaba si un string contenía cierta palabra bloqueada` ¿cuál sistema, una base de datos?, si es así, ¿por qué no crear las alternativas a las palabras en la base de datos como los ejemplos que colocas? es decir: `noob, n o o b, f ukc`, etc.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave sí, es una base de datos, las palabras filtradas están contenidas en arrays (tipo `["noob", "fuck", ...]`). Pero quiero concentrarme en una sola palabra de momento (encontré la palabra `fuck` como buen ejemplo porque existe `brainfuck`, palabra que no debería dar positivo). Ya lo adaptaré yo para múltiples palabras y usando leet2string y levenshtein.

Comment: @AntonioRoman, no se si estás enterado de [Perspective](https://www.perspectiveapi.com/). aunque está en estado Beta, creo que puede ayudarte.

Comment: Volví a editarlo, borrando información extra y centrándome todavía más en el problema del RegExp. Espero que ahora esté suficientemente claro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Palabra completa**. Para diferenciar `fuck` de `brainfuck`, utilizamos [`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary), que coinciden con los [límites de palabra completa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) (o [*word boundaries*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)).

```
/\bfuck\b/i
```

**Caracteres repetidos**. Para que coincida con cualquier cantidad de caracteres repetidos, usamos el [cuantificador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus) [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus), que repite la estructura anterior 1 o más veces. Así, `/f+/` coincide con 1 a infinitas `"f"`, o `/f+u+/` podría coincidir con `"fffffffffuu"`. Más info en [*Repetition*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
/\bf+u+c+k+\b/i
```

**Espacios intermedios**. Para permitir cualquier cantidad de espacios entre las letras, usamos un espacio repetido con un [asterisco](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-asterisk) (0 o más veces).

```
/\bf+ *u+ *c+ *k+\b/i
```

**Otros caracteres intermedios**. Para la solución que estás buscando, en vez de espacios, creo que te conviene permitir cualquier caracter no alfanumérico. [`\W`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-word) coincide con caracteres que no son "*catacteres de palabras*", es decir cualquier caracter excepto `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. De esta forma, coincidiría con textos como `"(f)(u)(c)(k)"`. Más info en [*Shorthands*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

```
/\bf+\W*u+\W*c+\W*k+\b/i
```

Demo:

```js
let pruebas = [
    "prueba",
    "palabra fuck bloqueada",
    "palabra brainfuck está bien",
    "con espacios f u    c k",
    "caracteres repetidos fuuuucccckkk!!",
    "con símbolos F::u--C**K!!!"
  ],

  regex = /\bf+\W*u+\W*c+\W*k+\b/i;

for (let string of pruebas) {
  console.log(`"${string}" -->`, regex.test(string));
}
```

---

**Múltiples palabras**. Además, se pueden incluir más de una palabra dentro de la misma expresión regular, [agrupando](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) con `(?:``expresión1``|``expresión2``)`. Por ejemplo, para que coincida con `fuck` o `ban`:

```
/\b(?:f+\W*u+\W*c+\W*k+|b+\W*a+\W*n+)\b/i
```

> Si se tuviera una lista extremadamente larga, como no conozco los límites para cantidad de caracteres o del regex compilado (o cómo afectaría la eficiencia), se debería probar antes de implementar en caso de que se piense usar con muchísimas palabras.

**Generar la expresión por código**. Un punto esencial en esta solución es poder generar el regex dinámicamente. La siguiente función toma un array de palabras prohibidas y devuelve un objeto RegExp con el patrón de esta respuesta.

```js
function regexDePalabrasProhibidas(arrListado) {
  let exprProhibida = arrListado.reduce(function(acum, item, index) {
    //unir las palabras con "|"
    return acum + (index ? "|" : "") +
      item.replace(/\w(?=(\w)?)/g, function(letra, tieneSiguiente) {
        //agregar "\W*" entre caracteres
        return letra + "+" + (tieneSiguiente ? "\\W*" : "");
      });
  }, "");
  //regex con límites de palabra y agrupado
  return new RegExp("\\b(?:" + exprProhibida + ")\\b", "i");
}



// --- EJEMPLO ---
let listado = [
    "fuck",
    "ban",
    "palabra3",
    "palabra4"
  ],
  regex,
  pruebas = [
    "prueba",
    "palabra fuck bloqueada",
    "palabra brainfuck está bien",
    "con espacios f u    c k",
    "caracteres repetidos fuuuucccckkk!!",
    "con símbolos F::u--C**K!!!",
    "frase con (b)(a)(n)"
  ];

regex = regexDePalabrasProhibidas(listado);

document.body.innerHTML = `Regex final: <code>/${regex.source}/${regex.flags}</code>`;
for (let string of pruebas) {
  console.log(`"${string}" -->`, regex.test(string));
}
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, con un tiempo de respuesta casi inferior a 1ms, es incluso mejor de lo que esperaba. +1

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor manera de acercarse a este tipo de reconocimiento de datos es utilizando el Algoritmo [Clasificador Bayesiano Ingenuo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clasificador_bayesiano_ingenuo), donde utilizando características comparativas podrías clasificar las diferentes cadenas de texto para categorizarlas como ofensivas o no. Tu aplicación iría "aprendiendo" a diferenciarlas, basada en experiencias previas de identificación de patrones (Machine Learning).

Te recomiendo leer sobre este algoritmo y a que te interiorices en Machine Learning, ya que puede ser muy útil para este tipo de comportamientos.

Cito la referencia de Wikipedia sobre Machine Learning:

> El aprendizaje automático o aprendizaje de máquinas (del inglés, "Machine Learning") es el subcampo de las ciencias de la computación y una rama de la inteligencia artificial cuyo objetivo es desarrollar técnicas que permitan a las computadoras aprender. De forma más concreta, se trata de crear programas capaces de generalizar comportamientos a partir de una información suministrada en forma de ejemplos. Es, por lo tanto, **un proceso de inducción del conocimiento**.